# Custom color of selected row in angular-ui-grid

Tags: ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I want to change the cell/row colors of an angular-ui-grid. From the documentation it seems I should use the cellClass for this. I want two colors for a striped look and another color for the currently selected row.

In my columnDefs I use a function to determine the proper cellClass. This works perfect on first load.

```
$scope.getCellClass = function (grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) {
    if (row.isSelected)
        return 'my-grid-cell-selected';

    if ((rowRenderIndex % 2) == 0) {
        return 'my-grid-cell1';
    }
    else {
        return 'my-grid-cell2';
    }
}

$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableRowSelection: true,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,        
    multiSelect: false,
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'EventDate', cellClass: $scope.getCellClass },
      ...
    ]
};
```

I don't know, however, how to update the cellClass of all cells of the selected row.
I have the following code that I thought would update the selected row but nothing happens although I can see that it is called.

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

    gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function(row){
        //??????
        gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ROW);
    });

};
```

Without my cellClasses the selected row gets colored differently.

Any idea how to achieve a customized color for the selected row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and easiest way to do this in my opinion is use the provided [ui-grid customizer](http://ui-grid.info/customizer/)!

Specifically what you're looking for to change the background color for odd vs even rows is to change the @rowcoloreven and @rowcolorodd fields.

To change the color of the currently selected row, update in the customizer the @focusedcell property and in addition follow [this tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/210_selection) and/or look at the second controller in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) to extend your selection from a single cell to the entire row.

I have also created a new [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TyiinoEVSugbO10tCFWy?p=preview) which shows how to implement row selection as well as how to change the row color defaults. Yes I know it's truly garish coloring - I thought it would help to really get the point across :). You can see in custom.css what is actually different from the uncustomized ui-grid css is

```
.ui-grid-row:nth-child(odd) .ui-grid-cell {
  background-color: #ffff33;
}
.ui-grid-row:nth-child(even) .ui-grid-cell {
  background-color: #ff22ff;
} 



.ui-grid-cell-focus {
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #b3c4c7;
}
```

If you need more direction let me know :)

Comment: Thanks for all the information, that seems to be a much better way to do it. The css output from the Customizer seems to be LESS code, which I am not that familiar with. I tried to compile it with one of the available online LESS compilers but it never ends up in a pure css file like yours, also my css file stays at only 958 lines. How do you create your custom.css from the customizer?

Comment: Hi @NicolasR I changed the variables [here](http://ui-grid.info/customizer/#) and then clicked the "Download Css" button at the top left of the page. Then I copied the output and pasted it into the .css file I created in the plunker named "custom.css".

Comment: That is really strange. Could you check with a local text editor how many lines the "Download Css" produces for you? For me it's always 958 lines.

Comment: Pasted into Notepad++ and I get 958 before any modifications and 1955 after I made the modifications mentioned above. See the note at the top of the customizer *The customizer currently only works with LESS defined for the core. Less for the features are not currently compiled into the included download.* It appears they've compiled their core css with LESS but once you make an edit to the customizer it is no longer fully compatible and so you get the "pure" css file. See [here](http://lesselements.com/) for details on LESS Elements

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong but whatever I do with the customizer, I never get more than 958 lines for the download and it never contains the color I set for @focusedCell. Anyway, I will use your css and set my colors there.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the way to do it with CSS:

```
.ui-grid-row-selected.ui-grid-row:nth-child(odd) .ui-grid-cell,
.ui-grid-row-selected.ui-grid-row:nth-child(even) .ui-grid-cell {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: blue;
} 

.ui-grid-row-selected.ui-grid-row:nth-child(odd) .ui-grid-cell.ui-grid-cell-focus,
.ui-grid-row-selected.ui-grid-row:nth-child(even) .ui-grid-cell.ui-grid-cell-focus {
  outline: 0;
  background-color: blue;
} 

.ui-grid-row-selected.ui-grid-row:nth-child(odd):hover .ui-grid-cell,
.ui-grid-row-selected.ui-grid-row:nth-child(even):hover .ui-grid-cell {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: This works, thank you. How did you get this result? I've been using the customizer variable: '@focusedCell' many different ways. I've been able to override everything else. Please explain how came to this answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This just overrides whatever was set in the grid CSS - you want to force the color to be the same if it's selected regardless if the row is odd or even and also if it's selected AND hovered AND/OR focused. This seemed to cover all those bases without writing more javascript. I played around with variables as well but was never able to achieve the behavior I wanted with them. The accepted answer doesn't cover the hover behavior, so not sure why that was accepted...

Comment: i had to add !important because it was not overriding for some reason.